# Efficiently create graph structure from many 100d vectors in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, vector, data-structures, graph

I have millions of real-valued vectors. The dimension of the vectors is 100.

I'd like to generate graph structure with given threshold that determines whether two vectors are connected or not.

If threshold is 3, pair of vectors [(2,0,0,0...), (0,0,0,...)] are connected each other, and [(4,0,0,0,...), (0,0,0,0,...)] are not connected, respectively.

Apparently, the most naive way is brute-force. Pick two vectors and calculate Euclidean distance. If the distance is greater than the threshold, those two vectors are connected. After repeating these operation, we can get graph structure. However, it's not tractable because I have millions of vectors with 100 dimension.

My questions are:

- what is an efficient way to generate such graph structure?
- how do I realize it on Python?

Comment: Slamming this down to 3D: if 2 points are at most 3 distance away they are connected? So `(0,0,0)` and `(0,0,3)` connected? `(2,0,0)`, `(0,2,0)` and `(0,0,2)` all connected to eachother (`2*sqrt(2) ~ 2.8`)? `(0,0,0)` and `(2,2,2)` not connected (`sqrt(3*2^2) ~ 3.5`)?

Comment: I guess you could store all these points in a 100 dimensional sparse matrix in numpy, after which you can probably reduce finding near neighbours to some matrix multiplication of some kind. As for storage of the graph, there's a bunch of graph databases that work with python, a decent overview here: http://www.slideshare.net/fphhotchips/a-quick-review-of-python-and-graph-databases

Comment: @Swier thanks. Yes. Every two vectors should be connected if the Eucllidean distance between them is less than threshold.

Comment: @Swier Of course memory efficiency is important, but computational complexity to generate graph structure, say adjacency matrix, is my main concern. Is it possible for such graph DB to generate adjacency matrix from vectors?

Comment: @Swier i forgot to mention that my vectors are not sparse. Sorry.

Comment: what might work, but I haven't tried anything like this with this many points, is just having an all-zeroes 100D matrix spanning your space, and then if there's a vector pointing to (2,3,4,....) you just set `matrix[2,3,4,...]` to `1` to represent your point. then once you've converted all your points to this you can pick sectors out of your matrix to compare all the points in them 1 sector at a time (the sectors should overlap at least your threshold) and ignore the rest (they're too far anyways), this would reduce the number of comparisons.

Comment: @Swier Thank you for concrete method. What does "sector" mean? Is your method applicable to real valued vectors?

Comment: scaling down to 3d again: you have a big cube in your n-D space (in this example 3) that contains the locations all your vectors point to. You then dice up this cube into smaller cubes (sectors) and compare the points within these.

Comment: Come to think of it, the more dimensions you have, the more likely points are to be near (for large n 'near' roughly equals 'on') the surface of your volume. Which means you could somehow (no idea how) project everything onto 2D and measure distance then for an approx. graph. But that is probably something worth writing a thesis on

Comment: @Swier Thank you. I understand what "sector" means. I could not find why picking up two vectors inside the same sector is enough to check their distances. I think vectors near borders of the sectors might be close each other.

Comment: I agree reducing dimensionality might be efficient especially when dimensionality of vectors is large and the number of vectors are relatively small. I am afraid that in this case, too many vectors for dimension reduction to work well.

Comment: What are the real values of the vectors like? Are they constrained to an interval, e.g. [0, 1]? And are they, within that interval, distributed *somewhat* uniformly?